# use of $_GET to get value in same page in php?

Tags: php, get

I am writing a code to perform action in php. When i started the page it shows the error below:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\page.php on line 19 for the $action.
```

and when the action occurs it does not show for the $dev also. When i start the page there is no action  and no $dev on the page.

So the error shows. how can i fix the problem ?

```
<?php
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$dev =$_GET['dev'];
if ($action == "viewfootage"){


}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code. its clear that you are accessing an object with undefined properties, You can check the existence of the properties using isset() function of php

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for the existence of `$_REQUEST['action']` and `$_GET['dev']` using the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['action']))
    $action="";//or any value for which you capture the desired output
```

Same thing goes for `$_GET['dev]`

If you want to check for all variable in one line use logical OR operator

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['action']||!isset($_GET['dev']))
```

Comment: how can i use !isset  in one line for multiple variable

Comment: you can ofcourse use multiple isset by seperating with && or ||.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    $dev =$_GET['dev'];
    if ($action == "viewfootage"){


    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    $dev = $_GET['dev'];
    if ($action == "viewfootage"){


    } 
}
```

Check whether the url consists of action and dev params

Comment: some subaction are also inside the action